# Ambiguous Function Call when One Definition is in a Namespace

Tags: c++, function, struct, namespaces

I have a simple program containing the following code:

```
namespace nam
{
    struct S{};
    void f(S *){}
}

void f(nam::S *){}

int main()
{
    nam::f(nullptr);

    nam::S s;
    f(&s);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect that this will compile fine because I am calling `f` the second time without specifying namespace `nam`.  However, upon compiling the code, I get this error:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:9: error: call of overloaded ‘f(nam::S*)’ is ambiguous
     f(&s);
         ^
main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: void f(nam::S*)
 void f(nam::S *){}
      ^
main.cpp:4:10: note: candidate: void nam::f(nam::S*)
     void f(S *){}
```

Compiler and version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 5.3.1-14) 5.3.1 20160409
```

After trying this with different compilers, similar errors are returned.  This seems to be a defined part of C++.  I can't find anywhere on the internet where it says that calling a function with a struct in `namespace nam` as a parameter effectively implies `using namespace nam;` and requires `::f` to remove ambiguity.  I have 2 questions about this:

1. Where is this defined in the C++ standard?
2. Is there a good reason for this behavior?

Personally I like to avoid `using namespace x;` and similar.  I want the compiler to give me an error when I don't specify a namespace.  This behavior stops the compiler from doing so, and this means my code is inconsistent in places, because I occasionally forget to specify the namespace when calling functions like `f` that are not declared globally anywhere.

Comment: The C++ feature is called ADL for "Argument Dependent Lookup".  This makes overload resolution search inside function arguments' samespaces.  The most cited benefit is reducing syntax verbosity when using operators on objects defined within a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in the comments, this is due to argument-dependent lookup.  I guess now I'll have to figure out now if I want to always specify the namespace in my code where this would make it unnecessary, or never specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of f(nam::S*) is outside of the namespace of 'nam'

change:

```
void f(nam::S *){}
```

to:

```
void nam::f(nam::S *){}
```

(or just move the enclosing namespace bracket) and all should be fine.

if your call to f(&s) in the current namespace was intentional then you need to specify this by changing the function call to

```
::f(&s)
```

Comment: I intentionally implemented the global function globally -- I'll edit my question to make it clearer.